# Why is "tuple([0])" printed as "(0, )"?

Tags: python

While converting lists to tuples in python 2, I noticed that converting any list with a single item to a tuple produces a comma after the item.

```
>>> tuple([0])
(0,)
>>> tuple(['i'])
('i',)
```

What is the reason for the comma being shown?
Does it cause any unexpected behaviour other than how it is printed?

I also noticed that a single tuple must be declared with a comma.

```
>>> (0)
0
>>> (0,)
(0,)
```

Presumably this is to make an expression like

```
>>> 5 * (2 + 3)
25
```

instead of

```
>>> 5 * (2 + 3)
(5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Comment: Because `(0)` is not a tuple. It is the *comma* that makes the expression a tuple. The parentheses are there to avoid confusion in expressions where a comma has a different meaning, but they are otherwise optional if there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Because [tuple has a special print function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Objects/tupleobject.c#l241) that overrides the normal `repr` for Python objects, to handle the comma special case.

Comment: I agree that it isn't (quite) a duplicate since the emphasis is on why tuples are *printed* that way. The question isn't deep, but it isn't purely redundant.

Comment: I guess what I'm really interested is the justification of this display, especially given parentheses for the sake of ordering operations are only used on input. i.e. '(0)' is printed as '0'

Comment: While 0 and (0) are identical, (0) and (0,) are not. It would be confusing if an object printed as "(0)", yet when you type that in you get a very different object. In short, for consistency's sake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so that the output is a valid Python representation of the object, which is what `repr` is supposed to produce. (`str` is the same as `repr` in the case of tuple, since there's no compelling reason for them to differ.) The trailing comma is necessary, otherwise it is not actually a representation of a tuple.

From the Python docs about `repr`:

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. This is the same value yielded by conversions (reverse quotes). It is sometimes useful to be able to access this operation as an ordinary function. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object.

```
>>> eval(repr(tuple([0])))
(0,)
```

If the comma was not produced, this would not hold.